# given number A, find a number B which is bigger than that by using same digits available in the number A

Tags: algorithm

You have given a positive number. You have to find a number which is immediate bigger than that by using same digits available in the number.

use same digits with same number of time, coming in positive integer and if a small number is not possible then we have to return -1.

For example:
(1) You have given a number 7585 , your output should be 7855 .
(2) 7111, return -1.

Thanks,

Zhong

Comment: Is it a homework? Or an interview question?

Comment: And what have you tried? Is this homework? We're not going to do your work for you.

Comment: Next time please specify your solution or thoughts

Comment: Can't put an answer since it's closed, but here is some perl code: http://codepad.org/WoJ9FMZR

Answer (score 2):

Easy:

```
def findnext(i):
  array = digitsOf(i)
  n = max_int
  for perm in permutations(array):
    if(number(perm) > i):
      n = min(number(perm), n)
  if n=max_int:
    return -1
  else:
    return n
```

Comment: Is that python or pseudocode?

Comment: Both... I started with psuedocode, but then I removed some words and ended up with python. So it's good psuedocode, and buggy python code.

Answer (score 1):

Find a bigger digit after smaller (start from the least significant digit), then swap them.

Answer (score 0):

convert to string
break into individual numbers and push into an array
sort the array descending
array to string
string to number 
if new number is higher than old, return it, if not return -1